# SQL calculated field based of data in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have two tables, Engineering table and Instrumentation table. In the Engineering table I have the columns and possible data below:

```
Tag                 |            Speed Control                       
PC-1234             |
ME-1235             |
BF-1236             |
```

In the Instrumentation Table I have the following columns and data

```
Function         |        Tag   
SC               |        1234    
SC               |        1235    
SC               |        1237
```

I want to automate the Speed Control column in the Engineering table to say Yes or No IF there is a line of data in the Instrumentation table with the function as SC and the Tag column have matching data with the number part of the Tag column in the Engineering table. So the results would like like the below:

```
Tag                 |            Speed Control                        
PC-1234             |             Yes    
ME-1235             |             Yes    
BF-1236             |             No
```

Please help with the best way to do this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: which databse system are you using?

Comment: My company is using SQL Server

Comment: The `Engineering.Tag` column is storing multiple pieces of information. This is bad design. Split it up into its separate parts in different columns.

Comment: I have calculated columns that does split up the Tag column to match the Function and Tag columns in the Instrumentation table. This design is because of the drafting software my company uses. I hope to get away from it this is year, but for now this is how the software is set up. Can I create a calculated column off of another calculated column in another table?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a separate column in the `Engineering` table for this. You just need a view which you can query

```sql
CREATE VIEW EngineeringSpeedControl
AS

SELECT
  e.Tag,
  SpeedControl = CASE WHEN i.Tag IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
FROM dbo.Engineering e
LEFT JOIN dbo.Instrumentation i
    ON i.Tag = RIGHT(e.Tag, LEN(e.Tag) - 3)
   AND i.[Function] = 'SC';
```

Unfortunately, due to the poor design of the tables, you need to muck around with string manipulation.

Ideally you would have the `Engineering.Tag` column split into separate parts, so you could just do a straight join

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.Instrumentation i
    ON i.Tag = e.Tag
   AND i.[Function] = 'SC';
```

Answer (score 0):

as i don't know if the Tag column in engineers is always of the same format, i keep my query so that it can have similar design xxxxx-nnnnnnnnn with a minus between.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Engineering] 
SET [Speed Control] =
CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Instrumentation] i WHERE RIGHT([dbo].[Engineering] .[tag],CHARINDEX('-', (REVERSE([dbo].[Engineering] .[tag]))) - 1) = CAST(i.[Tag] AS VARCHAR(10))) then 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
WHERE [Speed Control]  IS NULL
```

result will be

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to turn Speed Control into a calculated column? I can remove that column and come back with a calculated column???

Comment: or a Trigger possibly?

Comment: No generated coluna don't
t work that way trigger are if course possible, if you need to change as fter an insert update or delete

Comment: How would I set up a trigger to automatically populate the Speed Control column in the Engineering table based off the Instrumentation table having a matching Function and Tag?  There could be 100's of Tags in the Engineering table and possibly 50 Speed Control lines in the Instrumentation table.

Comment: For engineers a before insert update and delete trigger and for instruments a after Insert update delete trigger, you can use the answers here and search for triggers with before and after

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and use a function in calculated columns

```
   create table instrumentation([Function]  varchar(200) null,  Tag varchar(200) null)  

  insert into instrumentation values('SC', '1234'),('SC', '1235'),('SC', '1237')


 create Function fn_Speed (@tag varchar(200))
 returns varchar(200)
 as
begin

declare @tagg varchar(200)= (select SUBSTRING(@tag, charindex('-', @tag)+1,10))
declare @result varchar(200)
--return  @tagg

If exists (
select  1 from instrumentation where tag =@tagg)
    select @result= 'True' 
else 
    select @result= 'False' 
return @result
end

  Create table engineering (tag varchar(200), Speed   as dbo.fn_Speed (tag) )

  insert into engineering(tag)values('PC-1234'),  ('ME-1235'), ('BF-1236')
```